# authenticate website in qt

Tags: qt, authentication

how do i go about in authentication of a particular website say facebook on qt?please help.i am new to qt.

say i want to use facebook in qt without using qt's webkit.i want to use the rest apis.the first step i want to do is to authenticate a valid user with a username and password.how do i link this username and password to be entered in qt to that of facebook. how do i start?

Comment: Could you please elaborate your question in detail. it will be help full for us to answer

Comment: dupe? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332698/qt-client-for-facebook

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it myself.

However the authentication you are talking about sounds like a html action, for that you are going to need to use the QtWebkit and the [QWebPage](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qwebpage.html), you can then issue JavaScript calls with the mainFrame()->[evaluateJavaScript();](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qwebframe.html#evaluateJavaScript) function.