# Qt client for Facebook

Tags: qt, facebook, rest, httpclient

I would like to use **Facebook** API (http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/API)   in my `Qt Application`.

I don't want to use `WebKit`. Is it possibile to use `QNetwork` only?

Is there any example on how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you seen KFacebook, the KDE client for Facebook?

[KdePlayground and KFacebook](http://ftp.sayclub.com/pub/X/KDE/snapshots/kdeplayground-pim.tar.bz2)

They have a library for Facebook API and a Plasma Applet as well.

It's easier using jQuery, probably. But Qt4 can do the work, I think.

Answer (score 4):

Use QNetworkAccessManager to access the web without an actual browser.

Comment: you can't you have to Authorization and Authentication for Desktop Applications via browser 
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Authorization_and_Authentication_for_Desktop_Applications

Answer (score 0):

You can also use **QHttp** directly

Comment: QHttp is no longer the preferred method, Qt want people to use the QNetworkAccessManager for new projects:

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qhttp.html