# facebook authentication using qt

Tags: qt, facebook

can authentication for facebook be done without a web browser in qt? the way i want to authenticate is to enter a username and password in  text boxes and pass it as parameters in the url? is it possible? please help. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332698/qt-client-for-facebook) by [altuzar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/274119/altuzar):

> Have you seen KFacebook, the KDE client for Facebook?
>
> [KdePlayground and KFacebook](http://ftp.sayclub.com/pub/X/KDE/snapshots/kdeplayground-pim.tar.bz2)
>
> They have a library for Facebook API and a Plasma Applet as well.
>
> It's easier using jQuery, probably. But Qt4 can do the work, I think.